# Node.js lower performance on Ubuntu 12.04.3 because of libc

Tags: performance, node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

We are making profiling of our node.js application (Node v.0.10.22) on Ubuntu 12.04.3. It shows huge CPU occupying by libc-2.15.so. How to determinate what's going on and how to decrease impact from libc?

```
 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  77875   79.4%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
   2276    2.9%    LazyCompile: *clearBuffer _stream_writable.js:289
   2276  100.0%      LazyCompile: *onwrite _stream_writable.js:243
   2276  100.0%        LazyCompile: *WritableState.onwrite _stream_writable.js:96
   2276  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~<anonymous> fs.js:1675
   2276  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~wrapper fs.js:508
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably seeing Node.js sleeping in a system call.

As [Ben Noordhuis said](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/qBpH64C-no8/DwaVcrb0xfgJ):

> That's probably node.js sleeping in the epoll_wait() system call. 
>   Future versions of node.js will filter out such ticks but right now 
>   that's not possible, you have to keep your application busy when 
>   profiling.

You can also read [this relevant thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/_U0MmS6rUl4) on the node.js google group.